# Given 10 digits, how many ways can they be arranged so that two odds cannot be adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $10$ digits, where each digit can be an integer from $0$ to $9$, how can I determine the number of ways to arrange the numbers so that two odds are not adjacent?

Repetition of digits is not allowed.

So far, I have figured out the total number of possibilities: $$10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 10!$$

Then I had planned to subtract the number of bad possibilities from the total number of possibilities.$$10! - X$$ Where $X$ is all the bad possibilities, which means $X$ is all the possibilities where two odds could be next to each other in the $10$ digits.

I know that for each number, $5$ odds can be selected, how can I use this information to figure out the answer to the question?

Comment: If you only care about odd or even for a second, how many ways can you distribute the five odds and the five evens so that no odds are adjacent?

Comment: Hint: put the odds in a row (how many possibilities?) and then separate consecutives by placing an even (how many possibilities?). After that only one even number is left and must be placed. Watch out for multiple counting.

Comment: Are the digits all distinct? The way you're talking about the possible solutions seems to imply that they are, but I notice that you don't actually say so anywhere in the question.

Comment: @DavidZ it says in the question that repetition is not allowed.

Comment: Oh, so it does, somehow I missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are six different admissible assignments of odd (`O`) and even (`e`) numbers:

```
OeOeOeOeOe
OeOeOeOeeO
OeOeOeeOeO
OeOeeOeOeO
OeeOeOeOeO
eOeOeOeOeO
```

For these arrangements of parity there are $5!$ ways of fixing the odd numbers, and the same number of ways to fix the even numbers. Thus there are $6×5!×5!=86400$ ways.

Comment: the final one might have an issue with starting $0$ digit. Not sure if it's allowed. One would need to substract some options.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it was not specified in the question that the result had to be a _10-digit number_.

Comment: It's just 10 digits, not a 10 digit number. It's fine.

Answer (score 9):

Let $O$ and $E$ be the odd and even numbers respectively.

The odd digits are $1,3,5,7,9$.

The even digits are $0,2,4,6,8$.

$_E_E_E_E_E_$

If you are filling the odd numbers in any $5$ blank spaces yiels a required number.

There are $6$ blank spaces. So the number of ways to select $5$ spaces among $6$ spaces $=6C5 =6$.

Number of possible shuffling on $5$ odd number is $=5!=120$.

Again,Number of possible shuffling on $5$ even number is $=5!=120$.

Thus total number of possibility is $=6×120×120=86400$.

Comment: Is there a reason the image has 11 spots? (`_E_E_E_E_E_`)

Comment: I think, there is no reason behind it. I just think logically and post the answer.

Comment: The logic seems off because you can assign more than one even number to one of the middle spaces and still get a valid solution. On the other hand, if you use both outer spaces, your solution will be invalid.

Comment: @Sumyrda, that's why there are _six_ blank slots for five odd digits. Consider `oEoEoE_EoEo`, where one of the middle blanks is left empty. Now there are two even digits next to each other in the middle and both of the outer spaces are used. On the other hand, if you put two of the five even digits in one of the "E" slots, you'll need to leave another empty since you run out of digits. Then you'll have to avoid putting two odds around that empty "E". You'll get the same possible orderings still, it just breaks this simple system of counting them.

Comment: @likkachu Ah, I get it now. Thank you! (I had odd and even mixed up in my head).

Comment: @MattHough  If we line up the five even numbers, this creates six spaces, four between successive evens and two at the ends of the row.  In order to separate the odds, we must choose five of these six spaces in which to place an odd number.  The number of blank spaces created when you line up $n$ objects in a row is $n + 1$ since there are $n - 1$ spaces between successive objects and two at the ends of the row.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost same as the previous answers, but I’m going to present it in an (arguably) less brute-force manner.

We first observe that if we partition the digits in any valid permutation into 5 pairs, each pair must have exactly 1 odd and 1 even digits, for otherwise, there must be at least one (odd, odd) pair. (An unordered pair can only be (odd, even), (even, even) and (odd, odd). If (even, even) appears, since the numbers of odd and even digits are the same (both 5), there must be an (odd, odd) pair to balance it.)

Now fix the odd digits $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ and assign each digit an even digit. So there are $5!$ ways to assign the even digits.

Now we have $5$ (odd, even) pairs. To permutate them we have another $5!$ ways.

Next, we are going to merge the pairs. Since no two odd digits can be adjacent, we observe the following: if the previous pair is (even, odd), then the next pair must be (even, odd). Otherwise, we can choose to have (even, odd) or (odd, even).

Hence we can “switch” to (even, odd) at any of 5 pairs, and we can switch at most once. The remaining possibility is not to switch at all. Hence for every pair set containing 5 pairs, there are altogether $6$ switching possibilities.

It follows that the number of permutations is $5!\times5!\times6 = 86400$.